# Monitor color temperature changing software (like f.lux) that can temporarily switch color temperatures to a specified 'daytime' temperature, at night

Tags: windows, display, software-rec, f.lux

I'm using [f.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) to control my computer display's [color temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_temperature) (it automatically changes the color temperature of the computer screen depending if it's day or night).

At night, I would occasionally prefer to temporarily revert to the 'daytime' color temperature and use f.lux' 'disable for an hour' function, when playing video games, watching videos or viewing images that I don't want to use the 'night-time' color temperature setting on.

However, f.lux <strike>destroys my eyes</strike> reverts to the 6500K setting (default setting without f.lux), and not the 'daytime' color temperature setting I chose, when I use the 'disable for an hour' feature. I already got used to and prefer the 'daytime' setting that I set f.lux to, which is currently 6000K (and I'm trying to set it warmer as I adjust).

I would like to set it (or use another automatic color temperature changing-software) that can temporarily revert to my defined 'daytime' color temperature at night, and not revert to the 6500K default color temperature.

**Are there a workarounds to set f.lux to do this, or another color temperature-changing program that can do as I described? How do I configure it?**

My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks for your question. This isn't a feature request we've had before. Instead of using Disable for an Hour, you might consider using the f.lux settings menu (to the left of your system clock) to simply set a less cool color temperature. Then you can set it back when you're done. f.lux is designed to be automatic but it's easy to adjust it manually as well. We'll think about how to fix this for your use case in the future. cheers, @lorna from the flux software team.

Comment: How is it easy to adjust it manually? There is no option to perpetually put it into manual mode, which is what I want. I'd rather adjust the temperature manually.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [Iris](https://iristech.co/), it is very similar to f.lux. Basically, it uses the GitHub Open-Source f.lux code and extends it with such more features.

Possibly, the biggest advantage of Iris over f.lux is that it removes the flicker of the monitor, when brightness is reduced. Thus removing some additional eye strain. However, unlike f.lux the full version of [Iris](https://iristech.co/) is paid, with some free versions and free time.